# Format Date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, date, time, format

I have a date returned as a string:

```
date_str = "2018-08-17"
```

How would I format this in to another standard date format, eg. 17/08/2018 programatically without having to parse the string manually?

Comment: Ben, when you give an example make sure everything is a valid Ruby object (e.g.,  `"2018-08-17"` rather than `2018-08-17`, even though you state that the latter is a string) and assign a variable to each input object (I've edited to add the variable `date_str`), so that readers can refer to such variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Keep in mind that readers will cut-and-paste your code, so you don't want them to have to add quotes, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`::strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) to convert the string to date object, and then convert it to string again with [`#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) method.

```
require 'date'
Date.strptime('2018-08-17', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
# => "17/08/2018"
```

Comment: You may wish to include `require 'date'`, as this is pure Ruby. `strptime` is much preferrable to the lazy coder's fallback: [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse), as in `require 'date'; Date.parse("Theresa May had a rough week") #=> => #<Date: 2018-05-01 ((2458240j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Answer (score 0):

Chronic (https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) is a good gem for parsing date/time in any format, including human readable ones.

```
require 'chronic' 
Chronic.parse("2018-08-17")
```

The nice thing about Chronic is that you can parse even human readable times, like "tomorrow", or "next month".

```
Chronic.parse('tomorrow')
```